# Camera.Face Support in JellyBean or ICS on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, face-detection

I have been playing with the Face Detection capabilities for API 14+. On my 4.1 (JellyBean) on Galaxy Nexus, it seems that `Camera.Face.id, leftEye, rightEye, mouth` are not supported as `id` is always `-1` and all others are `null`. Is this also the case on ICS? I assume the GTalk Effects are done with the facial component API's support, maybe instead they handle the detection of facial components in app?

Comment: Did you call [getMaxNumDetectedFaces()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxNumDetectedFaces()) to make sure your device supports the API? Can you post more code showing how you are setting up the face detection?

Comment: yes, i did and (just to be more clear) i had no trouble detecting faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html#inhmethods), Camera.Face.id is an optional field and -1 is returned if it's not supported on your device. Same goes for the other fields returning null.

**Edit:**

No, the ICS build on the Galaxy Nexus does not support those fields. I just tested it:

```
 08-01 11:31:13.102: D/CameraActivity(13786): Camera.Face.id: -1
 08-01 11:31:13.102: D/CameraActivity(13786): Camera.Face.rightEye: null
 08-01 11:31:13.102: D/CameraActivity(13786): Camera.Face.leftEye: null
 08-01 11:31:13.102: D/CameraActivity(13786): Camera.Face.mouth: null
 08-01 11:31:13.102: D/CameraActivity(13786): Camera.Face.score: 100
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but yes, i know about the doc (as noted in the question). But I wonder if this behavior, i.e. not supporting facial component detection, present only in official 4.1.1 ROM for Galaxy Nexus. Maybe I should put it in a different way: Have you come across any system/device that fully support facial component detection?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your question. Are you asking if the ICS build for the Nexus supports those fields?

Comment: If you just want to detect facial features, you can use the old API 1 face detection. It does we span and midpoint detection.

Comment: yes, i wanna know if ICS build for GN supports them only for curiosity.